# My Thymeleaf/HTML doesn't like the th: prefix, and will not render the page when it is in the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form (using Java, Springboot and Thymeleaf) and it does not like when I add the th: prefix before the input area. If the th: is in the html, the whole page will not render. If I take it out, the page renders, but then I am not getting the actual clients input, I think because it is not working as a proper form. Any ideas on how to fix this? Am I missing a dependency or something behind the scenes?

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.Oli</groupId>
  <artifactId>ResourceWebsite</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>OliAffiliatePortal</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Thymeleaf Congfig file:

```
package com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.configuration; 

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer; 
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer; 
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; 
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus; 
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver; 
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver; 
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine; 

@Configuration 
public class ThymeleafConfiguration { 

  @Bean public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() { 
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver=new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver(); 
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("templates/"); 
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5"); 
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html"); 
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML"); 
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1); 
    return emailTemplateResolver; 
  }
}
```

My HTML /Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:modelAttributeth="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>DirectBind</title>
  <link th:replace="fragments/header :: head" />
</head>

<body>

  <div th:if="${param.sentMessageFail}">
    <div class="ui warning message">
      <i class="close icon"></i>
      <div class="header">
        Oops, your message failed to send!
      </div>
      Please try again, or send us an email at <a href="mailto:InternetBusinessDivision@Heffins.com">InternetBusinessDivision@Heffins.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div th:if="${param.sentMessage}">
    <div class="ui positive message">
      <i class="close icon"></i>
      <div class="header">
        Thank you for your message!
      </div>
      <p>We'll get back to you as soon as we can.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" class="ui form" th:object="${directBind}" method="POST" th:action="@{/send}">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Contact Name</label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{contactName}" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Address</label>
      <textarea th:field="*{formAddress}"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="two fields">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="ui fluid buttons">
      <a class="ui button" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</a>
      <div class="or"></div>
      <button class="ui blue button">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

My controller for the form:

```
package com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.controllers; 

import com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.models.OliDb.Document; 
import com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.models.ResourceWebsite.DirectBind; 
import com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.models.ResourceWebsite.Mail; 
import com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.services.EmailService;
import com.Oli.ResourceWebsite.services.StorageService; 
import com.sun.media.jfxmedia.logging.Logger; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.ui.Model; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile; 
import java.util.*; 

@Controller 
public class DirectBindController { 
  @Autowired private EmailService emailService; 

  @GetMapping("/directBind") 
  public String getDirectBind(Model model){ 
    DirectBind directBind = new DirectBind(); 
    return "directBind"; 
  } 

  @PostMapping(value="/send") 
  public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="directBind") DirectBind directBind) { 
    Mail mail = new Mail(); 
    mail.setFrom("no-reply@hgitservices.com"); 
    mail.setTo(new String[]{"stacief@hgitservices.com"}); 
    mail.setSubject("IME Self Support - User Message"); 

    Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    mail.setModel(mailModel); 
    try { 
      emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, directBind); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      return ("redirect:/?sentMessageFail"); 
    } return ("redirect:/?sentMessage"); 
  } 

  @RequestMapping(value="/email")
  public String email() { 
    return "emailMessage"; 
  }
```

Comment: Please review your post; the code needs formatting, and I think you have something going wrong with your controller paste.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, remove the explicit thymeleaf configuration. Also remove `spring-context-support` from your dependencies (as that is from on older Spring version and you will already get the right version from Spring Boot). Remove the version from `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` and `thymeleaf-layout-dialect` Spring Boot will manage those. Finally your `xmlns:th` should read `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"` not what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

You have forget to insert this instead in your html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

Your page can't process thymelaf without this declarations.

Comment: Or you can use `data-th-xxx` method.

Comment: changing the xmlns statement isn't helping. I just keep getting the same error: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor', referencing the first line where the th:field shows up.

Also, if I remove the th prefixes, the form will load, but it's not grabbing the client's input from the form on submit.